# Execute action each Nth appearence of a string

Tags: python, loops, download

There's a python [script](https://github.com/zaytoun/scihub.py) which allows doing batch downloads by processing a file with identifiers (DOI/URL) list. Sci-hub, however, is quite good at tracing such actions, so one needs to do small batches over significan amounts of time and/or constantly change proxies to remain undetected.

My idea, however, is that this may be automated (according to my almost non-existent knowledge of python, this should be the key part for this).

```
      elif args.file:
    with open(args.file, 'r') as f:
        identifiers = f.read().splitlines()
        for identifier in identifiers:
            result = sh.download(identifier, args.output)
            if 'err' in result:
                logger.debug('%s', result['err'])
            else:
                logger.debug('Successfully downloaded file with identifier %s', identifier)
```

So is it possible to:

1. Count the number of strings that have been processed
2. Run a loop which for every 10th iteration does a certain action (e.g. starts a pause of 3-5 minutes)

Comment: You might want to read this first....Then follow the story on what eventually happened to this poor guy....very sad. https://www.wired.com/2011/07/swartz-arrest/

Comment: @octofus: the answer to both questions is probably yes. But you need to show what code you have written, tell us what is not working, and let us help from there. It's unlikely that someone will just write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an index in your for-loop. You can use modulus, or reset each time:

```
    count = 0
    for identifier in identifiers:
        if count==10:
             action()
             count = 0
        count +=1
        result = sh.download(identifier, args.output)
        if 'err' in result:
            logger.debug('%s', result['err'])
        else:
            logger.debug('Successfully downloaded file with identifier %s', identifier)
```

If you only want to count successful iterations, you should put the code in the `else` block:

```
    count = 0
    for identifier in identifiers:
        result = sh.download(identifier, args.output)
        if 'err' in result:
            logger.debug('%s', result['err'])
        else:
            logger.debug('Successfully downloaded file with identifier %s', identifier)
            if count == 10:
                 action()
                 count = 0
            count +=1
```

You can also use `enumerate`:

```
    for count, identifier in enumerate(identifiers):
        if count%10 == 0:
              action()
        result = sh.download(identifier, args.output)
        if 'err' in result:
            logger.debug('%s', result['err'])
        else:
            logger.debug('Successfully downloaded file with identifier %s', identifier)
```